# Setting the end of rowset for the buffer failed with error code in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am getting the below error logged into the log file, when executing the 
SSIS sub-package seperately.

Error :

> Setting the end of rowset for the buffer failed with error code
>   0xC0047020.

When the main package is executed, the sub-package called within it  doesn't throw any error. The reason for executing the sub-package is to just check the data getting populated as part of the process instead of the waiting for the complete process to run. Also the sub-package doesn't have any dependency on the main package.
The only thing which is shared is the connection info, which is used across packages. 
I think the problem is due to too much logging of the info. in the log file. But not able to identify the property to be set in SSIS.
Pls. advise.